# how use columns of REF type instead of joins to link tables in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

here is my types and tables

```
create type Customer_t as object(
   cid char(6),
   cusname varchar(15),
   birthdate date,
   phone char(10),
   address varchar(50)
);
```

```
create type Car_t as object(
   regno char(9),
   make varchar(12),
   model varchar(10),
   mdate date,
   owner ref customer_t,
   value number(8,2)
);
```

```
create table Cars of car_t(
   regno primary key,
   owner references Customers
);
```

how can i insert data into Cars table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try an `INSERT ... SELECT` from `CUSTOMERS` filtered by the customer the car is for and use `REF()`.

E.g., if the ID of the customer is 1:

```
INSERT INTO CARS
       SELECT CAR_T('Reg', 'Mk', 'Md', SYSDATE, REF(C), 10000)
       FROM CUSTOMERS C
       WHERE C.CID = 1;
```

Comment: Hey sticky bit, thanks to your reply.it is helped for me.